# create a block in nginx for symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, configuration

```
server {
   listen 80; 

   server_name myapp.local
   root /home/jack/Documents/projects/php/myapp/web;

   location / { 
       #try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php?$query_string;
       #try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
       try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
   }   

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 last;
    }   

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }   

   access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp-access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp-error.log;
}
```

I've been trying to make this work but I couldn't and when I go to `myapp.local` I got `No input file specified.`. In the logs I have:

```
[error] 6867#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nginx/html/app.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: myapp.local, request: "GET /app.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "myapp.local"
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like it's trying to access `/usr/share/nginx/html/app.php`, why in the world is it doing that?
`nginx -v : 1.4.6`

Comment: Are you sure that this file is getting called, `/usr/share/nginx/html/app.php` seems to imply that your webserver is calling a different file using a  different root. Maybe a file that is defining `listen 80 default_server;`

Comment: I set the port number to 8888 to make sure: `myapp.local:8888` gives me exactly the same error and `myapp.local` gives this `403 Forbidden`. But I understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not guys, after 4 hours of debugging I realized that it was all about a poor missing semicolon after `server_name` statement. What a shame!